# uploading file Slim 3

Tags: php, slim

This is how I am posting data to my controller via GET

```
use Slim\Views\Twig as View;

class  place_pub_controller extends BaseController{

function place_pub($request , $response){
     $arr_requests=$request->getParams();
     $id=$arr_requests['prop_id'];
     $file=$arr_requests['my_file']; //output [object file]
```

Html FORM

```
<form id="frm_pub"  method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="container"></div> 
</form>

 <input type="file"> is placed dynamically within div class="container"
```

I am unable to get the file. How should i proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slim3 also uses the PSR-7 file so you should use the uploaded files function on the request

```
function place_pub($request, $response) {
    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    if (empty($files['my_file'])) {
        throw new Exception('No file has been send');
    }
    $myFile = $files['my_file'];
    if ($myFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $uploadFileName = $myFile->getClientFilename();
        $myFile->moveTo('uploads/' . $uploadFileName);
    }
}
```

Look at the [`UploadedFileInterface`](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/UploadedFileInterface.php) for more information what functions the file has.

Comment: getUploadedFiles() returns null

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form tag?

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee add your form to your questions

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee you cannot upload a file with the ``GET`` method. You need to use post

Comment: Ive change ( $app->get('/p_c', 'p_c_controller:p_c', function  ($request, $response, $db_connect) {
    
    return $response;
})->setName('p_c'); ) to 

(
($app->POST('/p_c', 'p_c_controller:p_c', function  ($request, $response, $db_connect) {
    
    return $response;
})->setName('p_c');

)

But am getting 500 internal server error. Must be one of the post